# Primality testing with binomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, primality-test

Here is what I observed :

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than 2.

Let $A = 2\cdot\binom{3n+1}{n}-\binom{3n}{n-1}+\binom{3n-1}{n-2}$

Let $p=2n+1$

$p$ is prime iff $A \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrsDUztubKszXSKtA25MpM09BIyszLz81MzNEwBgnpKBRoahnpIgvqFOgaamoji-gaAsWMNDVVNcDGaNraGukUFGXmlWgoAancVCVNGDc5P7cgvzizBCikaQ0AmxEkVQ==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ).

I tried with some prime and composite numbers below 350000 and I didn't find any counterexample.

Is there a way to prove it ? I think this is related to Wilson's theorem but I'm not sure.

Comment: The criterion is correct for all integers in the range $[2,3\cdot 10^4]$. I hoped that Wolfram Alpha could simplify the expression, but this is not the case.

Comment: Seems that in the case that $p$ is prime, all the binomial coefficients are congruent $1$ mod $p$

Comment: Nice observation !

Comment: I wrapped your GP code in Sage to make it interactive. There's probably a better way, but I don't know GP syntax. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNzsEKwjAMBuB7n6IUhGRrhXbgYaPgm8icrRRsG2bxIr67URF2Cv9HyJ9jKi2s89LEJUR5AvKHAUdJKztcaR8e8w2iUkqQf9JrEsW7jnorUgQ4p1Jz4oXhQ1oSds5sUZOx2G_FWDaHuIPvGfTe6V-Z4pGDwn9caqZ6T40JJ8EfIL4B1TQzKQ==&lang=sage

Comment: Thanks ! I don't know Sage at all

Comment: The prime case can actually be proven since the factors in the numerators of the binomials are congruent the corresponding factors in the denominators modulo $p$ and none of them are divisible by $p$. But for the composite case, I have no idea yet.

Comment: You can slightly simplify the expression by Pascal's rule, in fact you can show $A \equiv \binom{3n-1}{p}+\binom{3n}{p} \pmod {p}$. Not saying it's gonna help :)

Comment: @Sil yes I noticed that too indeed

Comment: @kijinSeija removed my previous comment as it was failing the same counterexamples $p=1093^2$ and $p=3511^2$ you have found, good find!

Answer (score 5):

Peter’s keen observation and idea is a ***Credit*** to the following partial answer.

I agree with what Peter said that the prime case is not difficult to prove using an interesting lemma below.

***Lemma:***

For any prime number $p$ and natural number $k$ satisfying $p<k<2p,$
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
k \\
p
\end{array}\right) \equiv 1 \quad  (\bmod p)
$$

Proof:

By definition, $$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
p
\end{array}\right)=\frac{k(k-1)\cdots(p+2)(p+1)}{(k-p)!}
$$

Rearranging gives $$
(k-p)!\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
p
\end{array}\right)=k(k-1) \cdots(p+2)(p+1)
$$

As $p\not |k,$ taking both sides in modulo $p,$ yields $$
\begin{aligned}
(k-p) !\left(\begin{array}{c}
k \\
p
\end{array}\right) & \equiv (k-p) !\quad (\bmod p) \\
\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
p
\end{array}\right) & \equiv 1 \quad (\bmod p)
\end{aligned}
$$

Rewriting $A$ gives $$
\begin{aligned}
A &=2\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 n+1 \\
2 n+1
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 n \\
2 n+1
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 n-1 \\
2 n+1
\end{array}\right) \\
&=2\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 n+1 \\
p
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 n \\
p
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 n-1 \\
p
\end{array}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

If $p=2n+1$ is prime, then using the lemma yields $$
A \equiv 2-1+1 \equiv 2 \quad  \pmod p
$$

Wish someone can help solve the converse!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Apparently, Wiferich primes squared (1093² and 3511²) are counterexample.